# How to fix 'Could not determine the dependencies of task...' provoked by firebase_messaging in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification

When I add the plugin 'firebase_messaging' to my pubspec.yaml, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugAidl'.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[20.0.0,20.0.0]], but resolves to 17.1.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I tried to change some versions of plugins but nothing makes it.

Here is my pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  circular_check_box: ^1.0.1
  photo_view: ^0.5.0
  dio: ^2.1.16
  fit_image: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  global_configuration: ^0.1.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3
  validators: ^2.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.21.0
  path_provider: ^0.5.0
  camera: ^0.4.3
  image_picker: ^0.5.4
  html: ^0.14.0
  bloc_provider: ^0.6.0
  flutter_bloc: ^0.12.0
  bloc: ^0.12.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A602, locale
    en-FR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your network could be restricting you, try connecting to another network.

Comment: Could you possibly be more specific? it's not clear how the network is involved here.